# Implement RBAC for Azure Blob Storage using an account in different Tenant?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-storage, azure-rbac

I'm setting up Role-based access control for our Blob storage in Azure.

Integration with AD is already available. However, I want to use a separate account's AD to access the blobs.Is it possible? and if so, how?

This is how it was set up so changes in architecture like remaking an AD or doing subscription changes can't be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only assign Azure RBAC roles on users and apps in the Azure AD tenant connected to the subscription.
If you want to give access to users in another tenant, you'll have to invite them as guests to the tenant connected to the subscription and then add roles to them.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: you are supposed to accept the answer if it helped you